# TortoiseHG Push a named branch until it is ready

Tags: mercurial, branch, tortoisehg

[image]
I have a new named branch that is NOT ready to be pushed. Meanwhile I developed on main branch. Now I want to push everything I have in main branch and hold the New branch. 
I know there is a "Secret draft" option without push the branch, but I am not sure if I can still make it 'Public' and push it later on.

Other than "Secret draft", is there a better, safer way to push main branch without pushing the new branch until it is ready?

Thanks

Comment: Secret is a great option, it will prevent it from being pushed until you make it 'draft' then push it later on.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
hg push -b default
```

In case you are not convinced, use

```
hg outgoing -b default
```

That is the command-line way. If you want to do it in TortoiseHg, select **Synchronize** on the toolbar, check the **Target** check box, and select the main branch in the combo box next to it.

**EDIT:**

However, I suggest you always push all your branches, even intermediate ones:

- Pushed changesets will be backed-up on other repos;
- If the branch is eventually merged in the default branch, you'll need to push those changesets too;
- If you want to discard the branch, you can always close it anyway.